# Chinese Android Devices. What browser is used by the WebView?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

China doesn't allow to install Google Chrome Browser by default in Chinese Android devices, and we can't ask to use it for testing. We noted that our Hybrid app got problems with Chinese devices

In Chinese Devices with Android 5+.

1.- Is the WebView Component different from the standard?

2.- What render engine and javascript engine is used by the WebView?    WebKit and V8?

3.- What Chinese browser behaves most similar to the WebView/Chrome?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with Chinese Android devices for many years.
Many of my clients have ONDA and CUBE tablet devices, running sometimes as old as 4.2.2 and mostly 5.0+.
It is a hard questions because there are so many flavors, and of course they do NOT have Google play services.
The WebView component on most of these devices works pretty well. The render engine appears to be WebGL. Here are some screenshots showing the Browser details the ONDA 7" tablets I use.
[image]
Here is the code I just tested on one of my ONDA 7" tablets and it works fine

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb_webview);

//Scroll bars should not be hidden
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
webView.setFitsSystemWindows(true);

//Enable JavaScript
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//Set the user agent
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AndroidWebView");

//Clear the cache
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
webView.setFadingEdgeLength(10);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

final Activity activity = this;
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
//progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading visualization ...");
        progressDialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                webView.destroy();
                finish();
            } });
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);
        if(progress == 100 && progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});

// Load the URL of the HTML file containing the JavaScript D3 code
webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```